# How to configure -D arguments in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testng

I am trying to run maven test and TestNG execution. I need to pass some config values to pom.xml and when I execute from command like using the -D flag, it is working. Now how can I add these values in Eclipse ?

My command line argument is like `-DUSERNAME=username` and in pom.xml I am getting it as

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <username>${USER_NAME}</username>                       
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

Now without specifying any run configurations, when I try to execute as TestNG and maven test it is showing an error which states `Reference to undefined variable USERNAME`. I tried adding envirnment variables in eclipse, but it is not working.

Comment: Try `MVN_OPTS` property

Comment: How can I do this ?

Comment: Sorry, it's `MAVEN_OPTS`, define an environment variable named `MAVEN_OPTS` and set its value to the java arguments you need like `-xms256m`

Answer (score 0):

if you go to your run configuration in Eclipse, there is a tab called **Arguments** where you can specify Program Arguments or VM Arguments

Comment: there it will be int he format -DUSERNAME=username . ?

Comment: Yes, under VM Arguments you need to set parameter in -DUSERNAME=username format

Comment: should specify the format, -1